# Meta should use a full URL for its Open Graph image

Tags: bug, design, hyperlinks, meta, twitter

The markup of this page has a meta tag which specifies its Open Graph image by a relative URL:

```
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="/content/stackexchangemeta/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=c34d758b103d&a" />
```

There is [a known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858577/open-graph-can-resolve-relative-url): a full URL is needed for Open Graph (the [spec](http://ogp.me/) does not say this explicitly, but all examples there are full URLs, and some parsers expect them).

As an illustration of this bug in action, tweets of Meta.SE posts fail to load the site icon: compare [Meta.SE tweet](https://twitter.com/NormalHumanSE/status/634805627395678208) and [Meta.SO tweet](https://twitter.com/NormalHumanSE/status/634096102099300353).

Comment: +1 and when it gets fixed it should point the image location to  'cdn.sstatic.net' i.e. where most of the static content delivered to SE Network sites.

Comment: @HackerKarma No, this Meta does not use CDN by design, being a testing ground for SE developers.

Comment: They use CDN on the Meta.SO posts.

Comment: Yes, because Meta.SO is just an ordinary per-site meta. This site,  [Meta.se], is the only one that's special. It gets built separately from other sites.

Comment: Ahha... Thanks for the clarification.